# supercell nscf kpoints for optical properties

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, k-points, optical-properties, supercell

I am calculating the optical properties of 200 atoms supercell with quantum espresso. What is the approximate number of the nscf kpoints (nk nk nk)should I start with, to avoid lengthy kpoints convergence for a large supercell.

Comment: Did you try a convergence test of your desired property with respect to k-point grid size?

Comment: Only one convergence test with such a large cell ( in the nscf mode which needs a dense grid) will take a long time that's why I would like to have a rough approximation where to start.

Comment: @hakouelhaj I'm facing the same problem, the convergence test take so long because the supercell is dense. If you found a solution please share it with me.